# email sent by PHP mail is uncoded for some but not all

Tags: php, html, email, header

I've been sending email from an osCommerce site via PHP mail.  Some people have responded to say that the message received is coming in "garbled" (their description).  Looking at what they received it seems that it's something with the headers, below is an example of what they are seeing:

```
X-Mailer: osCommerce

Content-Type: multipart/alternative;

    boundary="=_29f52435458f0625604b0644bed12e96"


--=_29f52435458f0625604b0644bed12e96

Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"

Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


<email body in TEXT format goes here>

--=_29f52435458f0625604b0644bed12e96

Content-Type: multipart/related;

    boundary="=_76ef682735a0ae864990f7224bfc9522"



--=_76ef682735a0ae864990f7224bfc9522

Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"

Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable



<email body in HTML format goes here>

--=_76ef682735a0ae864990f7224bfc9522--

--=_29f52435458f0625604b0644bed12e96--
```

It looks like there's something wrong with the headers.  What's making this difficult to solve is it displays like this for some and not others.  I've sent test mails to myself and I see it as it should be displayed.

This is not an osCommerce issue, it use to send with no issue, I tweaked it recently and now I can't revert it back to what it was.  My IDE allows me to track changes in files, and I've reverted all of my changes but the problem still persists.

Is the problem being caused by the two different boundary numbers?

What I'm looking for is to see if anything above looks out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending out mail in HTML format, specifically `multipart/mixed`. Not all email clients are capable of reading HTML mail. You might want to look into your emailing module to see if it can send out mail in plaintext format.

Comment: This is an email that (prior to my tweaking of the code) worked fine for both HTML and text.